# Bluetooth scan usin "hcitool scan" returns no results (Hama 00049229)

Tags: bluetooth

When I run `hcitool scan` the shell shows `Scanning...` for ~10 sec but doesn't show any results.

Same for `sudo hcitool scan`

(I have an Android phone and a PC nearby with bluetooth activated and set to visible)

(It did work the first time; I didn't change anything since then)

---

#### System Specs

Bluetooth adapter is a Hama 00049229 ([Manual](https://www.hama.com/webresources/article-documents/00049/man/00049229man_de_en_fr_72.pdf))

Chipset:
`Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0a5c:2121 Broadcom Corp. BCM2210 Bluetooth`

---

`hciconfig` shows:

```
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
        BD Address: 00:0D:18:01:5A:B3  ACL MTU: 1017:8  SCO MTU: 64:0
        UP RUNNING PSCAN
        RX bytes:849 acl:0 sco:0 events:39 errors:0
        TX bytes:420 acl:0 sco:0 commands:35 errors:0
```

(As commented by Tim Holt)
`hcitool dev` shows:

```
Devices:
    hci0    00:0D:18:01:5A:B3
```

(Also as commented by Tim Holt)
I ran `hcidump --raw` and the scan tool found all nearby bluetooth devices. Here is the dump (I scanned twice):

```
HCI sniffer - Bluetooth packet analyzer ver 2.4
device: hci0 snap_len: 1028 filter: 0xffffffff
< 01 01 04 05 33 8B 9E 08 00
> 04 0F 04 00 01 01 04
> 04 22 0F 01 65 FF 3D 83 15 00 01 00 04 01 12 BD 6B C9
> 04 22 0F 01 65 FF 3D 83 15 00 01 00 04 01 12 BD 6B C8
> 04 22 0F 01 65 FF 3D 83 15 00 01 00 04 01 12 BD 6B C9
> 04 22 0F 01 65 FF 3D 83 15 00 01 00 04 01 12 BD 6B C8
> 04 22 0F 01 65 FF 3D 83 15 00 01 00 04 01 12 BD 6B C8
> 04 22 0F 01 65 FF 3D 83 15 00 01 00 04 01 12 BD 6B CA
> 04 22 0F 01 65 FF 3D 83 15 00 01 00 04 01 12 BD 6B C7
> 04 22 0F 01 65 FF 3D 83 15 00 01 00 04 01 12 BD 6B C9
> 04 22 0F 01 65 FF 3D 83 15 00 01 00 04 01 12 BD 6B C7
> 04 22 0F 01 65 FF 3D 83 15 00 01 00 04 01 12 BD 6B C8
> 04 22 0F 01 65 FF 3D 83 15 00 01 00 04 01 12 BD 6B C5
> 04 22 0F 01 65 FF 3D 83 15 00 01 00 04 01 12 BD 6B CA
> 04 22 0F 01 65 FF 3D 83 15 00 01 00 04 01 12 BD 6B C5
> 04 22 0F 01 65 FF 3D 83 15 00 01 00 04 01 12 BD 6B C9
> 04 01 01 00
< 01 19 04 0A 65 FF 3D 83 15 00 01 00 BD EB
> 04 0F 04 00 01 19 04
> 04 07 FF 00 65 FF 3D 83 15 00 4D 69 63 68 69 73 2D 50 43 00
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

And then, everything went back to normal (broken) again and `hcidump --raw` showed:

```
HCI sniffer - Bluetooth packet analyzer ver 2.4
device: hci0 snap_len: 1028 filter: 0xffffffff
< 01 01 04 05 33 8B 9E 08 00
> 04 0F 04 00 01 01 04
> 04 01 01 00
```

`dmesg | grep -i bluetooth` shows:

```
[    5.875950] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.19
[    6.000541] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    6.202400] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    6.209332] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    6.586384] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   29.059873] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   29.059914] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   29.059972] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   29.132785] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   29.132869] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   29.132930] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

---

Raspberry Pi is model B Rev2

Installed packages:

- `bluetooth`
- `bluez-utils`
- `bluez-compat`
- `bluez-hcidump`

Comment: What does "hcitool dev" give you?  That should list your device.

Comment: Also, try doing an "hcidump --raw" in one window, then do an "hcitool scan" in another - you ought to see some output in the dump window.

Comment: `hcidump: command not found` -> [How can I find the package that contains a program in Debian?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/191977/how-can-i-find-the-package-that-contains-a-program-in-debian) I realize that question is closed as a duplicate, but the accepted answer is a good one, and if you click through to the duplicate you can check those answers too if you want.

Comment: Since it seems to work intermittently, it could just be the B cannot provide enough power, particularly if you have < 2A supply, so the device keeps failing.   If you have a powered hub you could test it in that.

Comment: @goldilocks sadly I don't have a powered hub and the PSU reads 1.5A

Comment: I can't promise that's the problem -- if it's *just* a pi B and the adapter (no keyboard, etc), you'd think it would be enough.   However, the B's do have a bit of a problem with power.  E.g., I have a wifi adapter that will shut down a B whenever I plug it in due to the sudden current draw, no matter what the power supply is.  To use it I have to start the pi w/ it plugged in.  But it does not do that to a B+.  In your case, the only way to rule the PSU out would be to try a 2 A one; they come with ipads, if you have any friends there.

Comment: I've been struggling with the same problem. I've used 2.0A, 2.1A, and it doesn't seem to work. command line 'hcitool scan' worked only when I got my PI closer to my phone. Strange behavior...  because, bluez-gui can discover devices which are much far away. the problems seems to happen only for command line discovery

Answer (score 6):

Try running the following:

```
sudo bluetoothctl
agent on
default-agent
scan on
```

Type `scan off` to stop scanning.

Answer (score 0):

From an [anonymous edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/73604):

---

Whenever you see something like:

```
[bluetooth]# scan on
Failed to start discovery: org.bluez.Error.NotReady
```

Power the chip on explicitly, type:

```
[bluetooth]# power on
[CHG] Controller 00:1A:7D:DA:71:08 Class: 0x500000
Changing power on succeeded
[CHG] Controller 00:1A:7D:DA:71:08 Powered: yes
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an ancient but wrong thread.
Unfortunately pretty typical- instead of explaining "hcitools" it switches to another commands....
It looks as hcitool {options} are not
My best guess

q5@q5-desktop:~$ hcitool dev
Devices:
hci1    00:50:B6:80:4D:5D

This should work

hcitool -i hciX scan --flush

BUT   it is failing

hcitool -i hci1 scan --flush
Scanning ...
Inquiry failed: Invalid argument

PS hcitool  --help has no "argument" -
**what is this missing argument**
?
?